# Maximize Mutual Information between multiple ("overlapping") RVs

Tags: entropy, combinatorics, mutual-information

I'd like to maximize the sum of Mutual Information between a RV $X$ and $K$ out of $N$ possible RVs $Z_i$.
$$ \max \sum_{i \in K} \text{MI}(X, Z_i) $$
However, when I unfold the sum I get
$$ \sum_{i \in K} \text{MI}(X, Z_i) = \sum_{i \in K} \text{H}(X) - \text{H}(X \vert Z_i)  = K \cdot \text{H}(X) - \sum_{i \in K} \text{H}(X \vert Z_i) \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i \in K} \min_i \text{H}(X \vert Z_i)$$
Because the RV might "overlap", I have to remove their Mutual Information again, e.g., for K = 2 I have:
$$\min_{i,j} \text{H}(X \vert Z_i) + \text{H}(X \vert Z_j) - \text{MI}(Z_i, Z_j)$$
or more general:
$$\min_{i} \sum_{i \in K} \text{H}(X \vert Z_i) - \sum_{(i,j) \in K} \text{MI}(Z_i, Z_j)$$
It's obvious that for large $K$ this expression is exploding in the number of possible combinations $K$ out of $N$. Is there any helpful (information-theoretic) optimization strategy to solve this problem? Also happy about research literature that tackles this problem.

EDIT: By overlapping I mean that the $Z_i$ can share information, such as shown in this publication [here](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/95323660ed2124450caaac2c46b5ed90-Paper.pdf) (note that the variables have different letters).

EDIT 2: In my context the RV $Z_i$ are manipulations on an unknown system $X$. I only have a limited number of manipulations I can make  on that system (budget constraints) and want to learn as much as possible about it (remove the uncertainty). Therefore, if I pick my manipulations greedily (i.e. just by their MI), then I might learn redundant things about the system (that's the "overlapping"). Hence, I want take this into account when selecting the $K$ manipulations which remove the uncertainty the most together.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'overlapping'? That the variables $\{Z_i\}_i$ are not independent? Giving some context on why you wish to maximize the sum of mutual informations might help.

Comment: Why not just compute the mutual informations between $X$ and all the $Z_i$ and then sum the largest $K$ ones? What do you expect to obtain from manipulating the formulae? Do you have some extra information about the $Z_i$ and $X$ that you have not yet mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I tried to clarify the issue with a picture (from a publication).

Comment: How do the $x$ and $y$ in the graph relate to your problem? Again, knowing the context of why you wish to maximize the sum of mutual informations might help to understand why you want to subtract some terms.

Comment: Next try ;-) Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This sounds like a case of Bayesian Experiment Design (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design). Can you check the wikipedia article and see if the framework is similar to that of your problem? Also, are the manipulations taking place successively (i.e. $Z_t$ taking place after $Z_{t-1}$)? By redundant, do you mean that different manipulations could bring information about similar subparts of $X$?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out! The manipulations take place simultaneously. And yes, different manipulations could reveal the same information of X (if they "overlap" like in the image above).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still a bit confused about some aspects of your problem, namely 1) why are the $Z_i$ random variables? Are they stochastic observations or deterministic inputs? 2) Can you give more concrete explanations about the structure of $X$, so that we can understand the concept of "overlapping"? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Unfortunately, there are two scenarios. In one $Z$ is a RV, in another it is a deterministic value, I wanted to focus on the RV one 2) X is a distribution over edges in a network (with iven number of nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be formulated more rigorously as an [Optimal Experimental Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design) problem. Rather than maximizing a sum of mutual informations, your initial goal is to maximize the mutual information $I(X,Z)$ where $Z = [Z_1, Z_2, \dots , Z_K]$. You did not specify over what you are optimizing, but I assume it is over some parameters/inputs on which $p(Z_i)$ implicitly depends.

The chain rule for the mutual information yields

$$
I(X,Z) = \sum_{i=1}^K I(X;Z_i|Z_{i-1}, \dots , Z_1)
$$

Hence, computing $\rm{max}_Z I(X,Z)$ can be rewritten as

$$
\rm{max}_{Z_1} \Biggl[ I(X;Z_1) + \rm{max}_{Z_2} \biggl[ I(X;Z_2|Z_1) + \rm{max}_{Z_3} \bigl[ I(X;Z_3|Z_1,Z_2) + [\dots] \bigr] \biggr] \Biggr]
$$

which is, as you explained, an intractable problem, since the algorithmic complexity scales exponentially with $K$. The classical solution is to perform so-called *myopic* optimization, i.e. to optimize for only one manipulation at a time while taking into account *previous* manipulations but not *future* ones:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^K \rm{max}_{Z_i} I(X;Z_i|Z_{i-1},\dots,Z_1)
$$

which is not as optimal as optimizing directly $I(X;Z)$, but which makes the problem computationally tractable. You can have a look at our recent preprints, in which we propose a particle-filtering based solution for mutual information optimization:

[Gontier, C., Surace, S. C., & Pfister, J. P. (2022). Efficient Sampling-Based Bayesian Active Learning. arXiv preprint arXiv:2201.07539.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.07539.pdf)